# Nestjs microservices with docker compose not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs, microservices

When I run nestjs with docker compose, the microservices redirects don't work, but in the "nest start" command, the application plays as I want.

gateway api response

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
gateway    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
gateway    |   errno: -111,
gateway    |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
gateway    |   syscall: 'connect',
gateway    |   address: '127.0.0.1',
gateway    |   port: 3000
gateway    | }
```

**Code**
docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  auth:
    container_name: auth
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./auth
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - docker_dev_cloud
  gateway:
    container_name: gateway
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./gateway
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - docker_dev_cloud
networks:
  docker_dev_cloud:
    driver: bridge
```

gateway dockerfile
**Code**

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .


EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

auth dockerfile
**Code**

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .


EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

help me please.

Comment: You don't show any of the actual configuration for the gateway, but it looks like you've set it to proxy to itself, 127.0.0.1.  Do you need to configure it to use the Compose service name `auth` of the back-end service instead?

Comment: Try using 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move localhost to service name for example:
127.0.0.1:3000 to
auth:3000